# Selectively picking texts from a (webpage) table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

my question is from a table on a webpage (sorry that I can’t give the web address because it’s a company’s internal one.)

The table looks like:

```
Status  Class_code  Major           Started from
Active  4562256     Global Finance      2013
Active  4588222     Global Finance      2014
Active  4552214     Trade Management    2014
Active  8631448     Law                 2012
```

And its codes are:

```
<TR class=Data align=left>
<TD class=TextColumn>Active</TD>
<TD class=NumColumn>
<DIV title="No:03">4562256</DIV></TD>
<TD class=TextColumn>Global Finance</TD>
<TD class=NumColumn>
<DIV title=2013>2013</DIV></TD>
...
<TR class=Data align=left>
<TD class=TextColumn>Active</TD>
<TD class=NumColumn>
<DIV title="No:04">4588222</DIV></TD>
<TD class=TextColumn>Global Finance</TD>
<TD class=NumColumn>
<DIV title=2014></DIV>2014</TD>
...    
<TR class=Data align=left>
<TD class=TextColumn>Active</TD>
<TD class=NumColumn>
<DIV title="No:05">4552214</DIV></TD>
<TD class=TextColumn>International Trade</TD>
<TD class=NumColumn>
<DIV title=2014>2014</DIV></TD>
...    
<TR class=Data align=left>
<TD class=TextColumn>Active</TD>
<TD class=NumColumn>
<DIV title="No:06">8631448</DIV></TD>
<TD class=TextColumn>Law</TD>
<TD class=NumColumn>
<DIV title=2012>2012</DIV></TD>
...
```

What I want to have BeautifulSoup to pick are the subjects created only in 2014, which are “Finance” and “International Trade”.

I am using below, but it gives all the numbers in columns.

```
find_number = soup.find_all('td', class_='NumColumn')

for fn in find_number :
    results = fn.find_all('div')
    print results
```

how can I only pick up the ones with “2014” (the “class code” is always on the 2nd column; the “Started from” is always on the 4th column)

thanks.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20404442/extracting-tables-from-a-webpage-using-beautifulsoup-4) but you ight get useful information from it

Comment: Updated my answer for your new HTML, but the HTML itself is inconsistent... see the answer for more details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply loop through the various `<tr>`s and check the details for each row in turn...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html =  """<TR class=Data align=left>
            <TD class=TextColumn>Active</TD>
            <TD class=NumColumn>
            <DIV title="No:03">4562256</DIV></TD>
            <TD class=TextColumn>Global Finance</TD>
            <TD class=NumColumn>
            <DIV title=2013>2013</DIV></TD>
            ...
            <TR class=Data align=left>
            <TD class=TextColumn>Active</TD>
            <TD class=NumColumn>
            <DIV title="No:04">4588222</DIV></TD>
            <TD class=TextColumn>Global Finance</TD>
            <TD class=NumColumn>
            <DIV title=2014></DIV>2014</TD>
            ...    
            <TR class=Data align=left>
            <TD class=TextColumn>Active</TD>
            <TD class=NumColumn>
            <DIV title="No:05">International Trade</DIV></TD>
            <TD class=TextColumn>4552214</TD>
            <TD class=NumColumn>
            <DIV title=2014>2014</DIV></TD>
            ...    
            <TR class=Data align=left>
            <TD class=TextColumn>Active</TD>
            <TD class=NumColumn>
            <DIV title="No:06">8631448</DIV></TD>
            <TD class=TextColumn>Law</TD>
            <TD class=NumColumn>
            <DIV title=2012>2012</DIV></TD>
            ..."""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):

    ## a list of all the divs in your tr.
    divs = tr.find_all("div")

    ## the subject is the first...
    subject = divs[0].text

    ## ...and the year the second "div" in divs.
    year = divs[1]["title"]

    if year == "2014":
        print subject
```

Updated for your new HTML, which seems to be inconsistent.  Currently outputs:

```
4588222
International Trade
```

However the TR for International trade does not follow the same pattern as the other TR: the code is in the TextColumn, and the text in the NumberColumn...

Comment: thanks, msturdy. my mistake: gave the wrong webpage source code. they are actually numbers instead of class names. could you please have a look? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a more robust, if more complex, solution you could try using regexes.

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Essentially, they let you specify the pattern that the data would be contained in.

For example,

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'div*/div')//This will get you any data in a div(That is spelled lowercase)
htmldocumentasstring = "However you would do that"
print p.match(htmldocumentasstring) //This will get you only the first result
```

So, it isnt the most pretty or easy solution, but it is a way.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to find the wanted '2014', and use findPrevious. :)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

aaa = soup.find_all('div', attrs = {'title':'2014'})

for bbb in aaa :
    ccc = bbb.findPrevious('div')
    print ccc.text
```